# Calculate daily mode of time series in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, xts

I am trying to calculate the daily mode of this time series. In the example data below, I would like to see the mode of the `windDir.c` column per day.

Don't know how to use the `apply.daily()` wrapper given the fact there is no "colMode" argument. So, I tried using a custom function in `period.apply()`, but to no avail.  The code I tried, along with the `dput` follows.

```
ep <- endpoints(wind.d,'days') 
modefunc <- function(x) {
  tabresult <- tabulate(x)
  themode <- which(tabresult == max(tabresult))
  if (sum(tabresult == max(tabresult))>1)
    themode <- NA
  return(themode)
}

period.apply(wind.d$windDir.c, INDEX=ep, FUN=function(x) mode(x))
```

Reproducible data:

```
wind.d <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1280635200, 1280635200, 1280635200, 
1280635200, 1280635200, 1280635200, 1280635200, 1280721600, 1280721600, 
1280721600, 1280721600, 1280721600, 1280721600, 1280721600, 1280808000, 
1280808000, 1280808000, 1280808000, 1280808000, 1280808000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), windDir.c = structure(c(4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L
), .Label = c("15", "45", "75", "105", "135", "165", "195", "225", 
"255", "285", "315", "345"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", 
"windDir.c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily do this using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
wind.d %>% group_by(date, windDir.c) %>%
           summarise(count = n()) %>%
           summarise(mode = windDir.c[which.max(count)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Or base R:

```
 calMode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   return(ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))])
 }
 myModes <- tapply(as.character(windDir.c), INDEX = date, FUN = calMode)
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael, for the input.  When I ran your code, however, I got an error saying "Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors"

Answer (score 1):

Note that the code you tried and the output of `dput` you provide aren't consistent. The `dput` output isn't an xts object, and the code you supplied will only work with an xts object (`endpoints` fails on the data.frame you provided).

Assuming that `wind.d` is indeed an xts object, you can do this easily with xts:

```
wind.d <- structure(c(105, 75, 75, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 
  105, 135, 135, 165, 135, 135, 105, 135, 135), .Dim = c(20L, 1L),
  index = structure(c(1280635200, 1280635200, 1280635200, 1280635200, 
  1280635200, 1280635200, 1280635200, 1280721600, 1280721600, 1280721600, 
  1280721600, 1280721600, 1280721600, 1280721600, 1280808000, 1280808000, 
  1280808000, 1280808000, 1280808000, 1280808000), tzone = "",
  tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
  tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "",
  .Dimnames = list(NULL, "windDir.c"), class = c("xts", "zoo"))
apply.daily(x, function(x) which.max(tabulate(x)))
#                     windDir.c
# 2010-07-31 23:00:00       105
# 2010-08-01 23:00:00       105
# 2010-08-02 23:00:00       135
```

Comment: Thanks for finding an easy solution using the function I originally wanted to use.  Apologies for the inconsistency -- am just now learning how to meddle with xts time series objects.

Answer (score 1):

We can load the package `modeest` to use the function `mfv` (Most Frequent Value)

```
library(dplyr)
library(modeest)
wind.d %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(mode = mfv(windDir.c))
```

Output:

```
                 date mode
1 2010-08-01 06:00:00  105
2 2010-08-02 06:00:00  105
3 2010-08-03 06:00:00  135
```

If there are multiple modes we need to specify the element we would like to retrieve. Otherwise it will return an error. For instance, the first element:

```
mfv(iris[iris$Species=="setosa", 1])
[1] 5.0 5.1
# dplyr
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mode = mfv(Sepal.Length)[1]) 
     Species mode
1     setosa  5.0
2 versicolor  5.5
3  virginica  6.3
```

### sqldf

For those interested in `sqldf`, using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334714/calculating-the-mode-with-sqlite-with-grouping):

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT date, 
            (SELECT [windDir.c]
            FROM [wind.d] 
            WHERE date = tbl.date
            GROUP BY [windDir.c] 
            ORDER BY count(*) DESC
            LIMIT 1) AS mode
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date
            FROM [wind.d]) AS tbl")
```